# three.js Water2 refuses to be transparent

Tags: three.js, transparency

I'm trying to create a water surface via the three.js example object "water2".

This is a demo of the object:
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=water#webgl_water

I use this code to create the water surface, which is taken directly from the demo code:

```
    const waterGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 16, 16 );
    water = new Water( waterGeometry, {
        color: '#aabbcc',
        scale: 4,
        flowDirection: new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 ),
        textureWidth: 1024,
        textureHeight: 1024
    } );
    water.position.z = 0.1;
    scene.add( water );
```

The water plane renders (as you can see in the left image); However the water surface is not transparent like in the demo scene on the right image. What could be the issue here? I checked the demo and there is nothing else there that interacts with the water plane. How is it possible it displays so differently on my own implementation, despite code being a 1:1 copy?

[image: mine vs demo implementation]

Comment: Do you mind sharing a live example that demonstrates the issue? Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/7gut4hy8/

Comment: I actually found the reason for the incorrect display now.

It seems that the water2.js example only works when viewed from positive y axis. The demo code doesn't have this issue because the water plane is placed along the x-z plane and isn't rendered from negative y anyway, because its one-sided.


Now I have two choices: fix the water system to work with a plane placed at x-y plane or shift my whole game logic around to work with the x-z plane.

Both seem terrible. I have no idea how the matrix conversions on water work. But I cant change my whole game just for a water surface either.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/17390